# how to enable/disable index in SYBASE 15.7

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to enable/disable index in SYBASE 15.7. Do you know the syntax for this?

I tried this:

```
    --line to disable index  

        alter table table name disable index index_name  
        go
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers. :?)

Answer (score 1):

Sybase ASE 15.7 does not support disabling indexes.  You will need to drop and recreate the indexes.

[Sybase ASE 15.7 documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X58868.htm):